How can I align this figure with the page numbering?
Hello I'm trying to align the figure with the page numbering. When I use \begin{center} I don't have problem usually. I have tried other things like begin{figure} or \begin{scope} but nothing. 
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage [utf 8]{inputenc}
\usepackage [ spanish ]{babel}
\usepackage {graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath , bm} %bm para letras en negrita dentro de entorno matemmatico%
\usepackage{amssymb}  %paquete de Geometría para los márgenes%
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=1.5cm, right=1.25cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz} %Para hacer dibujos en LateX%
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings} %Para introducir flechas en las lineas%
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,angles}  %Para utilizar Quotes=Comillas y angles con comando pic, creo%
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\usetikzlibrary {arrows.meta} %Para que funcione las flechas en tikz%
\usetikzlibrary {babel}  %Problem with babel and tikz using \draw% %Mirar en Stackexchange% 


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
    %Axis%
    \draw [-stealth] (-4,0) -- (4,0); 
    \draw [-stealth] (0,-3) -- (0,5);
    %Vectors%
    \draw [-stealth, ] (0,0) -- (4.84/2,1.74/2) node[]{};   
    %The hiperplane%
    \draw [] (-3.9/2.8, 10.7/2.8)--(3.48/2.8,-9.66/2.8);        
    %Coordinate ant its reflection over hiperplane%
    \draw [draw=none] (4.21/2, 5,4/2)--(0, 0);          
    \draw [draw=none]  (-7.08,1.56)-- (0,0);
    %Coordinates%
    \coordinate (A) at (1,0); 
    \coordinate (B) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (C) at ( 2.42/4 , 0.87/4 ); 
    %Second coordinates%
    \coordinate (D) at (2,0); 
    \coordinate (E) at (0, 0);
    \coordinate (F) at (4.21/2, 5.4/2);     
    %Third coordinates%
    \coordinate (G) at (4.21/2, 5.4/2);     
    \coordinate (H) at (0, 0);
    \coordinate (I) at (-0.68,1.88);    
    %Fourth coordinates%
    \coordinate (J) at (-0.68,1.88);    
    \coordinate (K) at (0, 0);
    \coordinate (L) at (-5/1.3, 1.1016949155/1.3);      
    %First Angle%
     \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) 
           pic [draw, angle radius=1.3cm ]      {angle = A--B--C};
    %Second Angle%
    \draw (D) -- (E) -- (F) 
           pic [draw,  angle radius=2cm ]   {angle = D--E--F};
    %Third Angle%
     \draw (G) -- (H) -- (I) 
           pic [draw, blue, angle radius=2cm]   {angle = G--H--I};         
    %Fourth Angle%
     \draw (J) -- (K) -- (L) 
           pic [ draw, blue, angle radius=2cm]   {angle = J--K--L};  
    \draw [blue] (4.21/2, 5.4/2)--(0, 0);           
    \draw [blue]  (-5/1.3, 1.1016949155/1.3)-- (0,0);        
    %Angles%
    \draw ( 1.9 , 1.4 ) node[] {$\theta$}; 
    \draw ( -2.1 , 1.2 ) node[blue] {$\pi/2 -\theta_0 -\theta$};    
    \draw ( 0.3 , 2.6 ) node[blue] {$\pi/2 -\theta_0 -\theta$};     
    \draw ( 1.3 , -0.3 ) node {$\theta_{0}$};        
    %Nodes%
    \draw (5.2/2,2/2)  node{$e^{\prime}$};  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
The figure is no center. Look at the number below.
\end{document}


To find the source of the problem, you can warp the whole tikzpicture into a \fbox{...}. This way you can see exactly how big the picture is.
From there, you can comment/uncomment your code to find the line which enlarges the images on the left side:
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage [utf 8]{inputenc}
\usepackage [ spanish ]{babel}
\usepackage {graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath , bm} %bm para letras en negrita dentro de entorno matemmatico%
\usepackage{amssymb}  %paquete de Geometría para los márgenes%
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=1.5cm, right=1.25cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz} %Para hacer dibujos en LateX%
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings} %Para introducir flechas en las lineas%
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,angles}  %Para utilizar Quotes=Comillas y angles con comando pic, creo%
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\usetikzlibrary {arrows.meta} %Para que funcione las flechas en tikz%
\usetikzlibrary {babel}  %Problem with babel and tikz using \draw% %Mirar en Stackexchange% 


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\fbox{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
    %Axis%
    \draw [-stealth] (-4,0) -- (4,0); 
    \draw [-stealth] (0,-3) -- (0,5);
    %Vectors%
    \draw [-stealth, ] (0,0) -- (4.84/2,1.74/2) node[]{};   
    %The hiperplane%
    \draw [] (-3.9/2.8, 10.7/2.8)--(3.48/2.8,-9.66/2.8);        
    %Coordinate ant its reflection over hiperplane%
    \draw [draw=none] (4.21/2, 5,4/2)--(0, 0);          
%    \draw [draw=none]  (-7.08,1.56)-- (0,0);
    Coordinates%
    \coordinate (A) at (1,0); 
    \coordinate (B) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (C) at ( 2.42/4 , 0.87/4 ); 
    Second coordinates%
    \coordinate (D) at (2,0); 
    \coordinate (E) at (0, 0);
    \coordinate (F) at (4.21/2, 5.4/2);     
    %Third coordinates%
    \coordinate (G) at (4.21/2, 5.4/2);     
    \coordinate (H) at (0, 0);
    \coordinate (I) at (-0.68,1.88);    
    %Fourth coordinates%
    \coordinate (J) at (-0.68,1.88);    
    \coordinate (K) at (0, 0);
    \coordinate (L) at (-5/1.3, 1.1016949155/1.3);      
    %First Angle%
     \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) 
           pic [draw, angle radius=1.3cm ]      {angle = A--B--C};
    %Second Angle%
    \draw (D) -- (E) -- (F) 
           pic [draw,  angle radius=2cm ]   {angle = D--E--F};
    %Third Angle%
     \draw (G) -- (H) -- (I) 
           pic [draw, blue, angle radius=2cm]   {angle = G--H--I};         
    %Fourth Angle%
     \draw (J) -- (K) -- (L) 
           pic [ draw, blue, angle radius=2cm]   {angle = J--K--L};  
    \draw [blue] (4.21/2, 5.4/2)--(0, 0);           
    \draw [blue]  (-5/1.3, 1.1016949155/1.3)-- (0,0);        
    %Angles%
    \draw ( 1.9 , 1.4 ) node[] {$\theta$}; 
    \draw ( -2.1 , 1.2 ) node[blue] {$\pi/2 -\theta_0 -\theta$};    
    \draw ( 0.3 , 2.6 ) node[blue] {$\pi/2 -\theta_0 -\theta$};     
    \draw ( 1.3 , -0.3 ) node {$\theta_{0}$};        
    %Nodes%
    \draw (5.2/2,2/2)  node{$e^{\prime}$};  
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{center}
The figure is no center. Look at the number below.
\end{document}


Ok, i have used mbox instead of  fbox and it is solved. This is now aligned with the page numbering. Thank you @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz

@Richard Remove the box after debugging. The fbox is just used to show the size of the image and help you find the problematic elements in the picture.

Alright, i will do it

There are two ways to absolutely center the tikzpicture w.r.t. a given point, in this case (0,0).  The first is to add extra space to the left or right to equalize the sides.
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage [utf 8]{inputenc}
\usepackage [ spanish ]{babel}
\usepackage {graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath , bm} %bm para letras en negrita dentro de entorno matemmatico%
\usepackage{amssymb}  %paquete de Geometría para los márgenes%
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=1.5cm, right=1.25cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz} %Para hacer dibujos en LateX%
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings} %Para introducir flechas en las lineas%
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,angles}  %Para utilizar Quotes=Comillas y angles con comando pic, creo%
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\usetikzlibrary {arrows.meta} %Para que funcione las flechas en tikz%
\usetikzlibrary {babel}  %Problem with babel and tikz using \draw% %Mirar en Stackexchange% 


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
    %Axis%
    \draw [-stealth] (-4,0) -- (4,0); 
    \draw [-stealth] (0,-3) -- (0,5);
    %Vectors%
    \draw [-stealth, ] (0,0) -- (4.84/2,1.74/2) node[]{};   
    %The hiperplane%
    \draw [] (-3.9/2.8, 10.7/2.8)--(3.48/2.8,-9.66/2.8);        
    %Coordinate ant its reflection over hiperplane%
    \draw [draw=none] (4.21/2, 5,4/2)--(0, 0);          
    \draw [draw=none]  (-7.08,1.56)-- (0,0);
    %Coordinates%
    \coordinate (A) at (1,0); 
    \coordinate (B) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (C) at ( 2.42/4 , 0.87/4 ); 
    %Second coordinates%
    \coordinate (D) at (2,0); 
    \coordinate (E) at (0, 0);
    \coordinate (F) at (4.21/2, 5.4/2);     
    %Third coordinates%
    \coordinate (G) at (4.21/2, 5.4/2);     
    \coordinate (H) at (0, 0);
    \coordinate (I) at (-0.68,1.88);    
    %Fourth coordinates%
    \coordinate (J) at (-0.68,1.88);    
    \coordinate (K) at (0, 0);
    \coordinate (L) at (-5/1.3, 1.1016949155/1.3);      
    %First Angle%
     \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) 
           pic [draw, angle radius=1.3cm ]      {angle = A--B--C};
    %Second Angle%
    \draw (D) -- (E) -- (F) 
           pic [draw,  angle radius=2cm ]   {angle = D--E--F};
    %Third Angle%
     \draw (G) -- (H) -- (I) 
           pic [draw, blue, angle radius=2cm]   {angle = G--H--I};         
    %Fourth Angle%
     \draw (J) -- (K) -- (L) 
           pic [ draw, blue, angle radius=2cm]   {angle = J--K--L};  
    \draw [blue] (4.21/2, 5.4/2)--(0, 0);           
    \draw [blue]  (-5/1.3, 1.1016949155/1.3)-- (0,0);        
    %Angles%
    \draw ( 1.9 , 1.4 ) node[] {$\theta$}; 
    \draw ( -2.1 , 1.2 ) node[blue] {$\pi/2 -\theta_0 -\theta$};    
    \draw ( 0.3 , 2.6 ) node[blue] {$\pi/2 -\theta_0 -\theta$};     
    \draw ( 1.3 , -0.3 ) node {$\theta_{0}$};        
    %Nodes%
    \draw (5.2/2,2/2)  node{$e^{\prime}$};
    \path (current bounding box.south west);
    \pgfgetlastxy{\xmin}{\ymin}
    \path (current bounding box.north east);
    \pgfgetlastxy{\xmax}{\ymax}
    \path (0,0);
    \pgfgetlastxy{\xorigin}{\yorigin}
    \path ({\xorigin-\xmin},\yorigin) ({\xorigin-\xmax},\yorigin);
    \draw[red] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
The figure is no center. Look at the number below.
\end{document}

The second is to reset the bounding box and only include what you need. The top and bottom coordinates are needed to reserve enough vertical space.  The side coordinates are gratuitous, but serve to automatically center the tikzpicture within the text area.
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage [utf 8]{inputenc}
\usepackage [ spanish ]{babel}
\usepackage {graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath , bm} %bm para letras en negrita dentro de entorno matemmatico%
\usepackage{amssymb}  %paquete de Geometría para los márgenes%
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=1.5cm, right=1.25cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz} %Para hacer dibujos en LateX%
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings} %Para introducir flechas en las lineas%
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,angles}  %Para utilizar Quotes=Comillas y angles con comando pic, creo%
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\usetikzlibrary {arrows.meta} %Para que funcione las flechas en tikz%
\usetikzlibrary {babel}  %Problem with babel and tikz using \draw% %Mirar en Stackexchange% 


\begin{document}

%\begin{center}
\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
    %Axis%
    \draw [-stealth] (-4,0) -- (4,0); 
    \draw [-stealth] (0,-3) -- (0,5);
    %Vectors%
    \draw [-stealth, ] (0,0) -- (4.84/2,1.74/2) node[]{};   
    %The hiperplane%
    \draw [] (-3.9/2.8, 10.7/2.8)--(3.48/2.8,-9.66/2.8);        
    %Coordinate ant its reflection over hiperplane%
    \draw [draw=none] (4.21/2, 5,4/2)--(0, 0);          
    \draw [draw=none]  (-7.08,1.56)-- (0,0);
    %Coordinates%
    \coordinate (A) at (1,0); 
    \coordinate (B) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (C) at ( 2.42/4 , 0.87/4 ); 
    %Second coordinates%
    \coordinate (D) at (2,0); 
    \coordinate (E) at (0, 0);
    \coordinate (F) at (4.21/2, 5.4/2);     
    %Third coordinates%
    \coordinate (G) at (4.21/2, 5.4/2);     
    \coordinate (H) at (0, 0);
    \coordinate (I) at (-0.68,1.88);    
    %Fourth coordinates%
    \coordinate (J) at (-0.68,1.88);    
    \coordinate (K) at (0, 0);
    \coordinate (L) at (-5/1.3, 1.1016949155/1.3);      
    %First Angle%
     \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) 
           pic [draw, angle radius=1.3cm ]      {angle = A--B--C};
    %Second Angle%
    \draw (D) -- (E) -- (F) 
           pic [draw,  angle radius=2cm ]   {angle = D--E--F};
    %Third Angle%
     \draw (G) -- (H) -- (I) 
           pic [draw, blue, angle radius=2cm]   {angle = G--H--I};         
    %Fourth Angle%
     \draw (J) -- (K) -- (L) 
           pic [ draw, blue, angle radius=2cm]   {angle = J--K--L};  
    \draw [blue] (4.21/2, 5.4/2)--(0, 0);           
    \draw [blue]  (-5/1.3, 1.1016949155/1.3)-- (0,0);        
    %Angles%
    \draw ( 1.9 , 1.4 ) node[] {$\theta$}; 
    \draw ( -2.1 , 1.2 ) node[blue] {$\pi/2 -\theta_0 -\theta$};    
    \draw ( 0.3 , 2.6 ) node[blue] {$\pi/2 -\theta_0 -\theta$};     
    \draw ( 1.3 , -0.3 ) node {$\theta_{0}$};        
    %Nodes%
    \draw (5.2/2,2/2)  node{$e^{\prime}$};
    \coordinate (bottom) at (current bounding box.south -| B);
    \coordinate (top) at (current bounding box.north -| B);
    \pgfresetboundingbox
    \path (top) (bottom) (-0.5\textwidth,0pt)  (0.5\textwidth,0pt);
    \draw[red] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
%\end{center}
The figure is no center. Look at the number below.
\end{document}


Although i have already solved this, I will take your answer into account for next time.
